# JavaScript Bitwise And operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, bitwise-and

This is a JavaScript program that's suppose to return the Max value of (a & b) which is also less than k ( i.e Max value of a & b < k )... But it returns a value one less than max value instead...
Note: a must be less than b;

```js
function data(n, k) {
  var res = [];

  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (var j = 2; j <= n; j++) {
      if (i >= j) continue;

      let a = i.toString(2);
      let b = j.toString(2);
      var c = a & b;

      c = parseInt(c, 2);
      res.push(c)
    }
  }

  var res = res.filter(function(e) {
    return e < k;
  });
  
  return Math.max(...res);
}

console.log( data(955, 236) );
```

**It returns 234, instead of 235...
I have tried other methods like Reduce and all... But i think my problem stems from where i compared the bitwise and of a & b...**

Comment: Please test the code you posted. It doesn't return 234, it logs an error. You have 935 iterations that iterate 935 times each... ‭874,225‬ iterations that compute I haven't the foggiest idea (something to do with binary,.. bitwise,.. bananas?). Of course that ridiculous amount of doing whatever exceeded the call stack. That's too much work to determine that 235 is less than 236.

Comment: I have... I returns 234.... This challenge is actually from hackerrank

Comment: Run the code on the question by clicking the blue button labeled: *Run code snippet*. Never heard of *hackerrank*, could you elaborate? Is it a site? If so, kindly post a link to the relevant location pertaining to this *challenge*

Comment: I used that button and it displayed 234. Hackerrank is a site actually. I have found a solution online eventually. I will post the answer now.

Comment: Here is the link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/js10-bitwise/problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function data(n, k) {
      var res = 0;

```
  for (var a = 1; a <= n; a++) {
    for (var b = 2; b <= n; b++) {
      if (i >= j) continue;

        if ((a & b) < k && (a & b ) > res ) {
              res = ( a & b) ;
         }

    }

  }


  return res;
}
console.log ( data ( 955, 236) ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I have no idea what this code is supposed to do...  But I can tell you that this code does not do what you think it does.

```
let a = i.toString(2);
let b = j.toString(2);
var c = a & b;
```

`toString` turns it into a string.  The `toString(2)` turns into a string that *represents* the binary value.  This is different from being the actual value.

bitwise operators, like `&` work on integers.  The compiler will try to turn the string into a number... but it will be working in base 10 at that point and thus, you'll get a totally different number than you expected.

Most like what you mean is `c = i & j`

You don't have to turn the numbers into binary.  Inside the computer they are *already* binary.  The computer just turns them into base 10 when you ask it show them to you.

Comment: `toString turns it into a string. bitwise operators, like & work on integers.` that's a bit misleading. `"231"&"132"` and `231&132` both work. But if  `toString(2)` converts the Number into a string in binary representation then the `"11100111"&"10000100"` or `11100111&10000100` is not the same as `231&132`

Comment: @t.niese Ah, true.  I did update the comment to reflect that.

Comment: Yes i know bitwise and works on integers, that is why i converted it back to an integer before checking the bitwise and... the parseInt (c,2) code converts it back to an integer.. This is actually a challenge from hackerrank

Comment: But it converts it back *after* the bitwise math ran on it, and the bitwise math does its own convert. 231 in decimal = 11100111 in binary,which will then be saved as string..  The bitwise operator will convert that string to the number of 11,100,111  (DECIMAL) and do the bitwise operators that way.

Comment: Oh sorry.... the bitwise and is meant to be done as show in my code.... I am suppose to covert it to string then check the bitwise and, after which i to return it back to an integer inorder to compare it with K to get the max value.